# Export model to excel/csv web api generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this API method in my ApiController:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("export")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Export([FromUri] int projectId)
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            sw.WriteLine("\"KeyId\",\"PageName\",\"KeyType\",\"KeyName\",\"LanguageCode\"," +
                         "\"KeyStatus\",\"KeyValue\",\"DateCreated\",\"DateChanged\",\"UserId\",\"KeysCount\"");

            var export = _projectService.GetExportModel(projectId);

            foreach (var row in export)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\"," +
                                           "\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\"",
                                           row.KeyId, row.PageName, row.KeyType, row.LanguageCode,
                                           row.KeyStatus,row.KeyValue, row.DateCreated, row.DateChanged,
                                           row.UserId, row.KeysCount));
            }

            var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            res.Content = new StringContent(sw.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/csv");
            res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Export.csv" };

            return res;
        }
```

In `_projectService.GetExportModel` i get `List<ExportExcelModel>`:

```
public class ExportExcelModel
    {
        public long KeyId { get; set; }
        public string PageName { get; set; }
        public KeyType KeyType { get; set; }
        public string KeyName { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public KeyValueStatus KeyStatus { get; set; }
        public string KeyValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public long KeysCount { get; set; }
    }
```

This method is works good, but all is hardcoded. In feature, if i add new property to model, i will need to update `StringWriter` and add this parameter to `foreach` loop. I searching for more generic way to do this. I want to update my model and see this change in CSV without change any line in webApi controller. This is possible?

Comment: Have you tried to find a third party library that will automatically export a list of objects to CSV?  If you can't find one, I'm sure it would be easy enough to write a generic method to take any type T and convert it to a comma delimited string.  Maybe using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late here but I think it may help others

I have developed an excel utility with the use of the NPOI package, which can

1. Simply takes your data table or the collection
2. And Returns you excel while maintaining all the data table/list data type intact in the excel.

Github Code repo.: https://github.com/ansaridawood/.NET-Generic-Excel-Export-Sample/tree/master/GenericExcelExport/ExcelExport

Looking for a code explanation, you can find it here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1241654/Export-to-Excel-using-NPOI-Csharp-and-WEB-API

It uses NPOI DLL and it has 2 cs files to include and then you are good to go

Below is the first file for reference **AbstractDataExport.cs**:

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace GenericExcelExport.ExcelExport
{
    public interface IAbstractDataExport
    {
        HttpResponseMessage Export(List exportData, string fileName, string sheetName);
    }

    public abstract class AbstractDataExport : IAbstractDataExport
    {
        protected string _sheetName;
        protected string _fileName;
        protected List _headers;
        protected List _type;
        protected IWorkbook _workbook;
        protected ISheet _sheet;
        private const string DefaultSheetName = "Sheet1";

        public HttpResponseMessage Export
              (List exportData, string fileName, string sheetName = DefaultSheetName)
        {
            _fileName = fileName;
            _sheetName = sheetName;

            _workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); //Creating New Excel object
            _sheet = _workbook.CreateSheet(_sheetName); //Creating New Excel Sheet object

            var headerStyle = _workbook.CreateCellStyle(); //Formatting
            var headerFont = _workbook.CreateFont();
            headerFont.IsBold = true;
            headerStyle.SetFont(headerFont);

            WriteData(exportData); //your list object to NPOI excel conversion happens here

            //Header
            var header = _sheet.CreateRow(0);
            for (var i = 0; i < _headers.Count; i++)
            {
                var cell = header.CreateCell(i);
                cell.SetCellValue(_headers[i]);
                cell.CellStyle = headerStyle;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < _headers.Count; i++)
            {
                _sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) //creating memoryStream
            {
                _workbook.Write(memoryStream);
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray())
                };

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue
                       ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
                       new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = $"{_fileName}_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.xlsx"
                };

                return response;
            }
        }

        //Generic Definition to handle all types of List
        public abstract void WriteData(List exportData);
    }
}
```

and this the second and final file **AbstractDataExportBridge.cs**:

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace GenericExcelExport.ExcelExport
{
    public class AbstractDataExportBridge : AbstractDataExport
    {
        public AbstractDataExportBridge()
        {
            _headers = new List<string>();
            _type = new List<string>();
        }

        public override void WriteData<T>(List<T> exportData)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                _type.Add(type.Name);
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? 
                                  prop.PropertyType);
                string name = Regex.Replace(prop.Name, "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim(); //space separated 
                                                                           //name by caps for header
                _headers.Add(name);
            }

            foreach (T item in exportData)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            IRow sheetRow = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sheetRow = _sheet.CreateRow(i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    ICell Row1 = sheetRow.CreateCell(j);

                    string type = _type[j].ToLower();
                    var currentCellValue = table.Rows[i][j];

                    if (currentCellValue != null && 
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(currentCellValue)))
                    {
                        if (type == "string")
                        {
                            Row1.SetCellValue(Convert.ToString(currentCellValue));
                        }
                        else if (type == "int32")
                        {
                            Row1.SetCellValue(Convert.ToInt32(currentCellValue));
                        }
                        else if (type == "double")
                        {
                            Row1.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(currentCellValue));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Row1.SetCellValue(string.Empty);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a detailed explanation, refer link provided in the beginning.

Comment: It is complaining about List for field _headers and _type in first file do you know what they should be type of?

Comment: both are simple List<string>(), not exactly sure about your error, check in the article it contains more detail, post more details, if you are still facing issue